# Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index ..?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following block of errors (worth noting that it repeats itself immediately after, I only copied one iteration for simplicities sake):

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 89

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 91

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 93

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 95

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 97

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 99

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 101

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /home/a-slsa/www/classes/ASC/ASCStaffData.php on line 103
```

The lines referenced are as follows (and yes, I know this is awful using deprecated functions, but this is not my code -- inherited a rather large project from someone else):

```
    $ascStaff['staffId'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"STAFF_ID") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"STAFF_ID") : NULL);

    $ascStaff['ownership'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"OWNERSHIP") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"OWNERSHIP") : NULL);    

    $ascStaff['firstName'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"FIRST_NAME") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"FIRST_NAME") : NULL);

    $ascStaff['lastName'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"LAST_NAME") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"LAST_NAME") : NULL);

    $ascStaff['ritEmail'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"RIT_EMAIL") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"RIT_EMAIL") : NULL);

    $ascStaff['otherEmail'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"OTHER_EMAIL") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"OTHER_EMAIL") : NULL);

    $ascStaff['address'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"ADDRESS") ?
                                mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"ADDRESS") : NULL);

    $ascStaff['phoneNumber'] = (mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"PHONE_NUMBER") ?
                                    mysql_result($dbStaffData->fetch,0,"PHONE_NUMBER") : NULL);
```

The thing that is confusing me is that the query, when manually entered into mysql, works perfectly.

Any idea why I am getting this error or how to fix it?

Comment: switch to `mysqli` extension, `mysql` extension is deprecated

Comment: @leemo mysql is an RDBMS and is most certainly not depreciated!! I think you meant the `mysql_` functions are depreciated as from PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: @leemo you're correct and I agree, unfortunately this project is far enough along and on a time constraint that it wouldn't be feasible to switch entirely over.

Comment: @James yes I meant the extension is deprecated.

Comment: It looks like the result set pointed to by `$dbStaffData->fetch` is empty. This could be because the query has failed, or maybe there's no data to match the query.

Comment: @Prefix Tell whoever is paying you it needs to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment: The `mysql` extension is deprecated so even if youre working on an old code base you should consider upgrading to `mysqli`.

Given that, generally this error indicates that the query has failed.

Check the query some way similar to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = 1");
if(!$result || !mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    die("Empty dataset.");
}
```